# Is there a simpler way to create an array in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I am trying to learn Go, and I am reimplementing something I have written in Python as a project. I am trying to send some basic commands to a Bluetooth LE device. Ultimately, I want a Characteristic I can write to, and it seems in order to do that with the BLE library, I first need to get a connection, find the services, filtering to the one of interest, and then once I have the Service, get its characteristics. That's all fine.

I am wondering if this is the best way of creating the filter array for getting the service of interest though:

```
var service_filter []ble.UUID

//s_uuid := ble.MustParse("00001820-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
s_uuid := ble.MustParse("1820")
service_filter = append(service_filter, s_uuid)

services, err := client.DiscoverServices(service_filter)
for _, s := range services {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s.UUID)
}
```

I am specifically asking about "service_filter". In other languages, I might do the following:

```
services, err := client.DiscoverServices([ ble.MustParse("1820") ])
for _, s := range services {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s.UUID)
}
```

Comment: `[]ble.UUID{ble.MustParse("1820")}`?

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I am looking for.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go. It's very good, and covers all the basics of langauge syntax, including [slice literals](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
services, err := client.DiscoverServices([]ble.UUID{ble.MustParse("1820")})
for _, s := range services {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s.UUID)
}
```

Initializing Slice in Go

```
var a = []int{1,2,3}
```